# How to press multiple button's at once on a WP7 in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, multi-touch

I am trying to make an app in c# for the windows phone 7 where you can press buttons to play a sample sounds to make music (Like a synthboard). But I am having the problem that you can't press 2 points at once. Now I have tried using multi touch but I am a little unsure on how to use it. When I tried it I got it to recognizing me pressing multi point's on the screen and it is playing the sound associated with how many fingers are on the screen. Can you help me cheers :)

Comment: *"I got it to recognizing me pressing multi point's on the screen and it is playing the sound associated with how many fingers are on the screen"* - what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Well I want I want it to do is to be able to press 1 button with one sound and another button with the other sound at the same time as what I have got it to do is when I press anywhere on the screen with 1 finger it plays 1 sound and when I press the screen with 2 fingers it plays a different sound.

Comment: This sounds like the device doesn't support the type action your looking for.  Unless you post code we really can't determine what your trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using classic events/taps to process touch input restricts you to single-touch interfaces only. You will have the same with Windows Phone Toolkit or Expression Blend Behaviors.

We’ll dig deeper into Silverlight for Windows Phone and how to process touch events directly using `Touch.FrameReported`.

A good starting point is this [link](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2.aspx).

After implementing your own logic, playing sounds is not too difficult.